# Error selecting cell range

Tags: excel, range, vba

When attempting to clear a cell range in a hidden worksheet I am receiving a "Select method of range class failed error" on line `.Range("A1:EC168").select`

Below is a copy of my code, thanks for any advice.

```
Private Sub ClearAll_Click()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim CompareTool As Workbook
Dim Sheetname As String
Set CompareTool = ThisWorkbook

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

For Each Sheet In CompareTool.Worksheets
    If Left(Sheet.Name, 8) = "Scenario" Then
    Sheetname = Sheet.Name
        With CompareTool.Sheets(Sheetname)
        .Visible = True
        .Range("A1:EC168").Select
        .Visible = False
        End With
    End If
Next Sheet

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't Select a cell in a hidden worksheet, but it looks like you are un-hiding it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to `Select` anything on an inactive sheet, so the solution would be to `Activate` it prior to the `Select` statement, though since the sheet is hidden, I'm not sure what the benefit of making the selection is...

```
    With Sheet
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .Range("A1:EC168").Select
    .Visible = False
    End With
```

You don't need to select the range to delete it, just do `.Range("A1:EC168").Delete`. This way, you don't even need to activate or make it visible:

```
    With Sheet
    .Range("A1:EC168").Delete
    End With
```

Comment: @Greg I still question why you bother to `Select` the range if the sheet is hidden, though :)

Comment: I'm adding a line of code after it is selected to delete the cell range. I had just removed that piece while trying to properly build the code

Comment: You don't need to select the range to delete it, just do `.Range("A1:EC168").Delete` :)  See addition to my answer.